# If a body part is colored by Hindus in Holi, will it be struck off on judgement day?

Tags: day-of-judgement, celebration, hindu

Some people says if your body part is colored by Hindus in [Holi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi) (festival of colours), it will be struck off on judgement day. Is it correct?

I live in India and at my work place our Hindu colleagues play holi and they also put color on my face and body.
I do not have any intention to take part in their celebration but I can't deny them also. Am I doing any sin?

Comment: I think you already answered your Question: It's not your intention so as far as you don't keep it afterwards or think or believe it would have any kind of influence on you and you reject it "inside", you didn't commit any thing

Comment: @Medi1Saif ya but is there any hadith which says about cutting the body part?

Comment: Well that sounds to me as a fabrication,a s i never heard a hadith mentioning hindus

Comment: *colored by **Hindus in Holi***, do you expect Prophet Muhammad to have encountered some Hindus at his time?

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting Question.

Where do these people get their fatwas from?

First thing to analyze is that the pagan Arabs didn't have any festival that resembled Holi. Nor did the Romans, Jews, Christians or Persians who travelled or lived in Makkah or Madina.

Hence, it's not mentioned any where in Quran or in any Sahih Hadith .

But I have heard why it is 'not recommended' to play Holi by some present day 'Indian' scholars:

**1) Muslims should not imitate others:**

> It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Umar said: The Prophet (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever imitates a people
>   is one of them.” (Abu Dawood)

**2) To avoid inter mingling and touching the other gender:**

In present day Holi gathering, there is a lot of interaction between both genders such as touching and applying colors to their friends, families and sometimes strangers. Islam discourages touching a non-mahram.

**3) To avoid consumption of alcohol:**

A majority of the Holi gatherings provide an alcoholic drink called [**Bhang**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhang). In earlier times it was restricted to only Hindu men but now is offered to all guest irrespective of gender or religion (age being the only barrier). Needless to say, bhang is prohibited in Islam.

As you see, there is a great chance of indulging oneself in sins (perhaps even unintentionally). Hence, it is advised against attending such gatherings.

As far as your office mates forcibly putting color on you, it is done without your will. And Allah is Just. Each action will be judged only as per it's intention.

I'd also suggest to explain to your office friends your reservations similar to how many of your Hindu friends might tell you why they don't eat meat due to religious reasons. There is no need to be shy in religion. And most non-muslims are rational human beings who understand and have empathy for others.